# Show a description of each site in the header, in smaller font

Tags: feature-request, design

Every site in the Stack Exchange network has a brief description, as in the list here - https://stackexchange.com/sites, but when you actually visit one, there's no explanation of what the site is for, unless you click through to the help, if you have already created your account on the site.

It would be nice to use the extra space in the header to show the site description, e.g. for Meta, "Q&A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites".

Another alternative would be to have the description in the top section of the right sidebar - some sites don't seem to have that header, so that might be a better solution.

I know it's possible to see what a site is for when you click on Ask Question, but it seems more helpful to have the description somewhere on the main page.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This already exists in the sign-up hero, though it would be nice to show something like that to new contributors on sites.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog It would be good to show to old users also - I've been on the network for years and could still use reminder about what the different sites are for - I just posted a question to the wrong site...

Answer (score 2):

Such description is already displayed for anonymous visitors or when just logged out:

> [image]

Once you have an account, the system assume you already know what the site is about, hence hiding this banner.

Comment: I find it useful to show to people who've already created accounts on the site. For example, if I want to make my first post on a site I already created an account on for the purpose of flagging spam as part of Charcoal.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog true. Turns out this was already suggested though.

Comment: Since your answer is now irrelevant due to the edits, maybe you should delete it.

Comment: Still relevant enough,  I think. It gives quick info about the banner, while the request to leave it in place is linked as a duplicate.

Comment: My comment on the question also refers to it.